# Visual Studio Extension KeyProcessor Alt Key

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Cant get event on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>. Example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. Event firing for <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but no <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
Mb problem in `IKeyProcessorProvider`? I have usercontrol, and want used inner control `ButtonKeyProc.KeyDownEvent+=`.

```
[Export(typeof(IKeyProcessorProvider))]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
[ContentType("any")]
[Name("ButtonProvider")]
[Order(Before = "default")]
internal class ButtonProvider : IKeyProcessorProvider
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ButtonProvider()
    {
    }

    public KeyProcessor GetAssociatedProcessor(IWpfTextView wpfTextView)
    {
        return new ButtonKeyProc(wpfTextView);
    }
}


internal class ButtonKeyProc : KeyProcessor
{
    internal static event KeyEventHandler KeyDownEvent;

    public ButtonKeyProc(ITextView textView)
    {
    }

    public override void KeyDown(KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Key == Key.E && IsAlt)
        {
            if (KeyDownEvent != null)
            {
                KeyDownEvent(this, args);
            }
        }           
    }

    public bool IsAlt
    {
        get { return Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftAlt) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightAlt); }
    }
```

Comment: Why not check [`args.Alt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.alt.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code. Need used args.SystemKey and Keyboard.Modifiers.

```
public override void KeyDown(KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.SystemKey == Key.E && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) != 0)
    {            
    }           
}
```