# How to handle Keyboard events in VSIX?

Tags: c#, .net, keyevent, vsix, onkeypress

I am working on VSIX project where I need to detect Enter key *OnKeyUp* event. How can I implement this in a *Text Adornment* project? I Need to detect the event when someone press key for changing the line in the editor.

Comment: take a look  maybe can help https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-detect-when-the-enter-key-pressed

Comment: OP and upvoter perhaps need a refresher of [ask]

Comment: @BUcorp This may work for *Tool Window* only. For me, there is no XML file that takes tags and attributes like that Microsoft document shows. I only have a *TextAdornment* listener/provider class that is providing the opened documents' details in *IWpfTextView* reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/daaf1fae-4fa1-4ac1-a864-afc19bbbfb1b/how-to-handle-keyboard-events-in-vsix?forum=vsx#54b1b42d-63d3-4594-8760-809eb60c95b7) thread of mine. We can use [KeyProcessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.keyprocessor?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) class for keyboard event handling. We can refer from [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268685/visual-studio-extension-keyprocessor-alt-key).