# Catch a key-press event

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I am wondering, if you could listen for any key-presses or key-combination within a Visual Studio Extension? Additionally could it be differentiated between key-press events within a document and within the focus on the Visual Studio Window itself?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question to me?

Comment: @IronAces Uhm, I am not quite sure what you are talking about. VS Extensions can be build with C# and I am trying to listen to key down events from within VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261450/how-to-handle-keyboard-events-in-vsix#60389592) solution. This may help you. Your question is quite confusing but here you can get more general information about Key event handling.

Comment: It would have enough to post the link as a comment, anyhow thanks a lot for the link though. I couldn't find anything for whatever reason.